# Sharpoint 2010 REST _vti_bin/listdata.svc returns no Attachments and users/groups

Tags: rest, attachments

I have a problem when I need to retrieve data via REST from SharePoint 2010 list. In the returned data Attachments and user / group column is not contains data. I do not know if it's because it's collections.
I have written a very simple code example and hope that there is someone who can help.

Edit 26/9-2016
since no one has answered this question, Is there someone who knows if it is possible is to get data into C# code, I can see the information I need in a Browser, but with what do I call this with (return object) , so I get data out in some kind of the structure/object?

DataServiceContext( new Uri(http://SPSite.net/sites/testsite/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Lycklist(1)/Attachments/)

```
enter code here

public static class REST
    {
        public static LyckDataContext GetContext()
        {
            LyckDataContext ctx = new LyckDataContext(new Uri("http://SPSite.net/sites/testsite/_vti_bin/listdata.svc"))
            {Credentials =  CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials};
                  return ctx;
        }


        public static List<MyItems> GetMyList()
        {
            LyckDataContext ctx = GetContext();

            List<MyItems> ItemList = new List<MyItems>();
            var myList = (from item in ctx.Lycklist select item) as DataServiceQuery<LyckData.LycklistItem>;
            // This depends on the client, if callback is needed.  
            // IAsyncResult res = myList.BeginExecute(GetResult, myList);
            try
            {
                foreach (var item in myList)
                {
                    MyItems newItem = new MyItems();
                    string allUsers = "";
                    if (item.Usersandgroups.Count > 0) // There is never any users??
                    {
                        foreach (var user in item.Usersandgroups)
                        {
                            allUsers += user.Name;
                        }
                        newItem.Users = allUsers;
                    }
                    if (item.Attachments.Count > 0) //There is also no attachment
                    {
                        foreach (var att in item.Attachments)
                        {
                            string temp = att.Name;
                        }
                    }
                    //There are no problems with strings
                    newItem.Title = item.Title;
                    newItem.Name = item.Mybodytekst;

                    ItemList.Add(newItem);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { string message = ex.Message; }


            return ItemList;
        }

        private static void GetResult(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            DataServiceQuery<LycklistItem> query = (DataServiceQuery<LycklistItem>)result.AsyncState;

            foreach (LycklistItem Item in query.EndExecute(result))
            {
                //code
            }
        }
    }      
        public class MyItems
    {        
        //Democlass
       public string Users { get;set; }
       public string Title { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string AttachmentsPath { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get Attachments using `$expand` operator. $expand is needed for `__deferred` properties, lookup columns and User/Group columns.

For all item use following end-point

```
_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Lycklist?$expand=Attachments
```

For single item

```
_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Lycklist(1)?$expand=Attachments
```

[image]

You can use my [SharePoint REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-rest-client/ojnaikgchcnginnmkmkonmdglhjikokd) to test/explore REST API.

Comment: Hi Atish, This is really good, but how do I get this output into my C # code, because I'm forced to send Credentials with. Therefore, I have created a web service and getting data into a DataServiceContext. I can see all data with Rest Client.

Comment: You have to change current C# code to bind Json with C# object

Comment: Hi @Atish  Yes, but how do I authenticate and how do i make the call to the service from the code? EX var response = ??  ----  I have searched the web and there are no examples of how it's done. there are a lot of small JavaScript snippet, but I need it in my backend code. Thank for you bother to spend the time, I am very grateful.